# Is there a way to make this slideshow move automatically?

Tags: javascript, recursion, lambda, functional-programming, closures

This is the slideshow that we used:

http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/blinds/

and this is the JS file:

http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/blinds/js/jquery.blinds-0.9.js

However, this slideshow doesn't have a setting that makes it go through each image automatically. You still have to click on the numbers below it to see the images. Does anybody know what to add into the javascript code to make it go through each image automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This solution uses closures and recursion.

```
var SlideChanger = function(seconds_each) {
  var index = -1; 
  // on the first cycle, index will be set to zero below
  var maxindex = ($(".change_link").length) - 1; 
  // how many total slides are there (count the slide buttons)
  var timer = function() { 
  // this is the function returned by SlideChanger
    var logic = function() { 
    // this is an inner function which uses the 
    // enclosed values (index and maxindex) to cycle through the slides
      if (index == maxindex) 
        index = 0; // reset to first slide
      else
        index++; // goto next slide, set index to zero on first cycle
      $('.slideshow').blinds_change(index); // this is what changes the slide
      setTimeout(logic, 1000 * seconds_each); 
      // schedule ourself to run in the future
    }
    logic(); // get the ball rolling
  }
  return timer; // give caller the function
}

SlideChanger(5)(); // get the function at five seconds per slide and run it
```

What we are doing here is exposing the inner function `timer` outside of the function in which it was defined (`SlideChanger`). This function (`timer`) has access to the variables defined inside of `SlideChanger` (`index` and `maxindex`).

Now that we have set up the variables in the enclosing environment and a function to return to the caller, we can set up the logical engine in `logic`. When `logic` is run, it uses `index` and `maxindex` to determine which slide should be shown next, shows the slide, and schedules itself to be run again in the future.

When called, the returning function calls `logic` to get the ball rolling. Then `logic` repeats indefinitely by scheduling itself to run in the future each time it is run.

So, to summarize, we call `SlideChanger` with a numeric argument `x`. It returns a function that, after being called, will change the slide every `x` seconds.

Another way to write the same concept.

```
(function(seconds_each) {
  var index = -1; 
  // on the first cycle, index will be set to zero below
  var maxindex = ($(".change_link").length) - 1; 
  // how many total slides are there (count the slide buttons)
  return function() { 
  // this is the function returned by SlideChanger
    var logic = function() { 
    // this is an inner function which uses the 
    // enclosed values (index and maxindex) to cycle through the slides
      if (index == maxindex) 
        index = 0; // reset to first slide
      else
        index++; // goto next slide, set index to zero on first cycle
      $('.slideshow').blinds_change(index); // this is what changes the slide
      setTimeout(logic, 1000 * seconds_each); 
      // schedule ourself to run in the future
    }
    logic(); // get the ball rolling
  }
})(5)(); // get the function at five seconds per slide and run it
```

JavaScript is a nice language with many functional programming constructs such as higher order functions (functions that either create functions or accept functions as parameters) and anonymous functions. For more info see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-javascript.html

Comment: Thanks for posting. But could you guide me as to where in the JS file should I insert this?

Comment: Try it at the bottom of jquery.blinds-0.9.js

Comment: Doesn't work. I inserted the block of code just before the "})(jQuery);" at the end. :? Did I do it correctly?

Comment: Try it just after that - at the _very_ bottom of the file.

Comment: Still not working. Placed it at the very bottom after "})(jQuery);". :|

Answer (score 4):

ecounysis's solution would work but it's unnecessarily complicated. Here's a simpler way using setInterval, modulo, and not wrapping it in an extra function:

```
function startSlideshow(ms) {
    var index = -1;
    var count = $(".change_link").length - 1;
    return setInterval(function() {
        index = (index + 1) % count;
        $('.slideshow').blinds_change(index);
    }, ms);
}
```

Comment: I also tried this one, placed it at the very end of this javascript (http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/blinds/js/jquery.blinds-0.9.js). Still didn't work. What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 0):

After a quick scan through the source, I didn't see a built-in API for auto-advancing the slides. However, you could use an alternative slideshow, like this one:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to include a timer on it and call the blinds_change event. That works for me.