# Where to put this block of script so that this slideshow can move automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I asked a question before on how to make the [jQuery Blinds slideshow](http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/blinds/) move automatically and somebody answered on this page (the one with 12 votes):

[Is there a way to make this slideshow move automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273617/is-there-a-way-to-make-this-slideshow-move-automatically)

Seems like the code is working for most people but I can't get it to work for me. I used the original demo file and placed the code at the very bottom of jquery.blinds-0.9.js, right after "})(jQuery);" but still the slideshow isn't moving. What am I doing wrong? I checked the class names and they are correct.

This is that block of script:

```
var SlideChanger = function(seconds_each) {
  var index = -1; 
  // on the first cycle, index will be set to zero below
  var maxindex = ($(".change_link").length) - 1; 
  // how many total slides are there (count the slide buttons)
  var timer = function() { 
  // this is the function returned by SlideChanger
    var logic = function() { 
    // this is an inner function which uses the 
    // enclosed values (index and maxindex) to cycle through the slides
      if (index == maxindex) 
        index = 0; // reset to first slide
      else
        index++; // goto next slide, set index to zero on first cycle
      $('.slideshow').blinds_change(index); // this is what changes the slide
      setTimeout(logic, 1000 * seconds_each); 
      // schedule ourself to run in the future
    }
    logic(); // get the ball rolling
  }
  return timer; // give caller the function
}

SlideChanger(5)(); // get the function at five seconds per slide and run it
```

Comment: the only line that looks like trouble is `$(.slideshow').blinds_change(index)` check that in the console

Comment: idk, but you should mark the "12 votes answer" as accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the last line `SlideChanger(5)();` in a `document.ready`, like this:

`$(function(){SlideChanger(5)();})`

Otherwise `$(".change_link").length` will prob return 0